# Prove that the surface of revolution S is locally conformal to a plane.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathbf{x} : U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S$ be the parametrization of a surface of revolution $S$:

$$
\mathbf{x} (u,v) = (f(v)cos(u), f(v)sin(u),g(v)), f(V) > 0,
$$ $$
U = \{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2; 0<u<2\pi, a<u<b\}
$$

Prove that the map $\varphi : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by

$$
\varphi(u,v) = \left(u, \hspace{0.2cm}\int \frac{\sqrt{(f'(v))^2 + (g'(v))^2}}{f(v)}dv\right)
$$

is a local diffeomorphism.

I must use that to prove that the surface of revolution $S$ is locally conformal to a plane.

To prove this I considered the following map $F$ from $S$ to a plane, given by:

$$ F(x,y,z) = (\varphi_1 (\mathbf{x}^{-1}(x,y,z)), \varphi_2(\mathbf{x}^{-1}(x,y,z)),0) $$

But I don't know how to prove that $F$ is a diffeomorphism

Comment: The tangent map of $\phi$ exists everywhere and vanishes nowhere (provided that the generating curve $(f, g)$ of the surface is regular, i.e., that $(f'(t), g'(t)) \neq (0, 0)$ for all $t$), so the Inverse Function Theorem guarantees that it is a diffeomorphism. But the condition of conformality is much stronger than the condition of being a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The parametrization  $x:U\subset{\mathbb{R}^2} \rightarrow  S$ of a surface of revolution $S$, is
$$x(θ, ϕ) = (f(ϕ) \cos θ, f(ϕ) \sin θ, g(ϕ))$$
such $f(ϕ) > 0$.

$$U=\{(θ, ϕ)∈ R^2: 0 < θ < 2π, a < ϕ < b\}$$

The map $φ:U \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2$  given by
$$ φ(u, v) = \left(u, \int \dfrac{\sqrt{(f'(v))^2+(g'(v))^2}}{f(v)}dv\right)$$
is a local diffeomorphism (calculation direct).

Let

$$u = θ, \qquad v = h(ϕ) = \int \dfrac{\sqrt{(f'(ϕ))^2+(g'(ϕ))^2}}{f(ϕ)}dv$$
the parametrization of the coordinate neighborhood $x(U) = V$ can be given by

$$y(u, v) = (f(h^{−1}(v))\cos u, f(h^{−1}(v))\sin u, g(h^{−1}(v)))$$

By direct computation the coefficients of the metric induced by y are given by (calculating $h^{−1}$ by using inverse function theorem),

$$E=G=(f'(v))^2 > 0, F = 0$$

Thus, $y^{−1}: V \subset{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a conformal map which again takes the meridians and parallels of the surface of revolution $S$ onto the straight lines of the plane.